# How can I implement this two column fluid-fluid layout, with extra width constraints on the first column, without using CSS 3 features?

Tags: html, css

Here's the layout:

[image: Fluid-Fluid Layout]

It is essentially a two column fluid-fluid layout, with the first column's specs being:

```
width: 30%;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 300px;
```

Height of the columns should be in-sync, but not a constant value.

For the record, I tried using table and table-cell displays, but Firefox, Safari, and Chrome ignore max-width for the table-cell, so that solution does not work.

Comment: Have you tried nesting an element in the left cell to give the max-width to?

Comment: The only way top make both columns fluid is to use percentages but this means that you are unable to set a max width.  You would have to go down the javascript route to achieve what you want

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution I worked out. See it live [here on my test server](http://colemantest.com/test/twoColumn.html).

Because you want to use both pixel values *and* percentages you inherently limit the percentages to work within the scope you define with pixel values. For example, this means that when the left column is its smallest (200px), that equates to 30% and forces the remaining 70% to be 466px. This is just a limitation of using both pixel values and percentages... but it’s the best I’ve got without using Javascript.

Hope this helps!

```
<head>
  <title>twoColumn</title>
  <style type="text/css">

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.wrap {
      background-color: yellow; /* for illustration's sake */
      margin: 0 auto; /* to center it all, for illustration's sake */
      min-width: 700px;
      max-width: 1000px;
      overflow: hidden; /* to hide the overrun from the 3000px of faux-column padding*/
    }

    div.column1 {
      background-color: blue; /* for illustration's sake */
      width: 30%;
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 -30% -3000px 0; /* to offset the faux-column padding */
      padding-bottom: 3000px; /* to create a faux-column appearance after the left column's content */
    }

    div.column2 {
      float: right;
      width: 70%;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">

      <div class="column1">
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1<br />
        column1
      </div> <!-- end .column1 -->

      <div class="column2">
        column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 column2 colunn2
      </div> <!-- end column 2 -->

      <div class="clear"></div>

  </div> <!-- end .wrap -->
</body>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. But could you please explain in more detail what column1's margins and padding-bottom are doing here? I changed the margin to `0 -1% -3000px 0` and it continued to work as far as I can see. But overall I am not following what's going on there. More explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Sure! The padding-bottom is the only thing that's odd here. By setting .column1 to have 3000px of bottom padding, it's extended well beyond what will likely be used. This extends the div's appearance to the bottom of div.wrap, where it's cropped by `overflow:hidden`. However, adding 3000px of padding to the column also increases the element's height by 3000px. The negative margin on the bottom is to offset that height, allowing the appearance of a column without the collateral damage. The -30% was to offset .column1's width, but it looks like it's no longer necessary. I'd set it to 0 now.

Comment: You might also find this article about creating two-column layouts useful: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/08/equal-height-columns-using-borders-and-negative-margins-with-css/ The above solution is a different play off of the article's idea of using the border property to create a faux-column.